# Push the image from jenkins server to the gke as a deployment

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created an LAMP image from the Dockerfile using Jenkins in Ubuntu VM. now I want to push the LAMP image to the gcr.io and also want deploy a Nginx pod using that LAMP image to a GKE cluster on the project.

[image]

Figure: 1

I used Google Kubernetes engine Plugins to connect with the Cluster as per above figure:1. I'm not understand how I need to define Kubernetes Manifests for the pic above. I got below error while build the configuration:

```
tagged gcr.io/xxx-xxx-xxx/lamp-stack:v0
FATAL: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LAMP/test.yaml
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LAMP/test.yaml
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:370)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:421)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at hudson.FilePath.newInputStreamDenyingSymlinkAsNeeded(FilePath.java:2109)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:2094)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:2086)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.Manifests.loadFile(Manifests.java:192)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.Manifests.<init>(Manifests.java:155)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.Manifests.<init>(Manifests.java:149)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.Manifests.fromFile(Manifests.java:173)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubernetesEngineBuilder.addMetricsLabel(KubernetesEngineBuilder.java:300)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubernetesEngineBuilder.perform(KubernetesEngineBuilder.java:266)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a the exception `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` because Jenkins is a self-contained Java-based program.

This error is thrown when an attempt is made to access a file that does not exist, in this case `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LAMP/test.yaml`. You have to make sure the file does exists in that path.

You can take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine) for further information on how to use Jenkins on Kubernetes Engine.

For adding the image to Container Registry you have to `docker tag` and `docker push` the image to the gcr.io hostname. You can find how to do it in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart#add-image).